# To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.Object)

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, soap

I am trying to build a web service to get attachment from outside for mail server and send it from there but I am getting below error:

> To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have
>   an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their
>   inheritance hierarchy. System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary
>   does not implement Add(System.Object). [InvalidOperationException:
>   There was an error reflecting type 'System.Net.Mail.Attachment'.]

My code is like below:

```
[WebMethod]
    public String SendMailWithAttachment(string mail_sender, string[] mail_receiver, string mail_subject, string mail_text, Attachment att)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Net.Mail.Attachment is not designed to be serialized into xml.  You will need to send the data required to construct the attachment and use it in the body of your web method.  For example, send a byte array with the data and a string with the name of the attachment:

```
[WebMethod]
public String SendMailWithAttachment(string mail_sender, string[] mail_receiver, string mail_subject, string mail_text, byte[] attachment_data, string attachment_name){
   using(var ms = new MemoryStream(attachment_data)){
       var attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms,attachment_name);
       ...
   }
}
```